# Building Python packages succeeds, but package is improperly built

Tags: linux, compiling, python3

When running `python3 setup.py build` it ended with this:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/linear_model/sag_fast.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/linear_model/sag_fast.cpython-34m.so
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn': Permission denied
```

Of course it could not write to `/usr/local/lib/` as no `sudo` was used. I'm wary of using sudo for this step.

This was the end of `sudo python3 setup.py install`:

```
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.18.dev0.egg-info
running install_clib
```

Looks good to me. However, when I try to `import sklearn` I get this error:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dotancohen/code/scikit-learn/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ._check_build import check_build
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/dotancohen/code/scikit-learn/sklearn/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
File "/home/dotancohen/code/scikit-learn/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
File "/home/dotancohen/code/scikit-learn/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
    %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /home/dotancohen/code/scikit-learn/sklearn/__check_build:
_check_build.c            setup.pyc                 __pycache__
_check_build.pyx          __init__.py               setup.py
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
>>>
```

**Should I run `python3 setup.py build` with `sudo`?** This is on Kubuntu Linux 15.10:

```
$ uname -a
Linux loathe 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 15.10 \n \l
```

**Note that the Ubuntu-packaged version of `python-scikits-learn` is for Python 2 only, and I need Python 3.**

Comment: Have you tried using sudo before asking? Looks like it couldn't install its library in the path, and after run, it can't find the library it tried to install.

Comment: @MatthewRock: I hadn't tried using sudo, that is quite specifically why I'm asking. I understand that the build stage should not need to touch the root filesystem, and I'm a bit too naive yet security-conscious to [try sudo](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root) every time something doesn't work. I would like to understand that "Yes, this _is_ supposed to require sudo" before I do it.

Comment: @MatthewRock: I've resolved the issue, and in fact `sudo` was not required for that step.

Comment: But of course it was - you just didn't build it yourself, so you did not need `sudo` for building - but you did need `sudo` for installing it.

Comment: @MatthewRock: I'm specifically referring to the build step, which was complaining about not being able to write to `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/538994/23087) which mentioned to configure which ATLAS (linear algebra package) version to use:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set libblas.so.3 /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3
$ sudo update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3 /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3
```

After that, I was happily surprised that in fact there was no longer a permissions issue, but I was getting this error on build instead:

```
sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Therefore I went over the results of `aptitude search python | grep dev` and decided that the following packages might help:

```
$ sudo aptitude install python3-numpy-dev python3.5-dev libpython3.4-dev
```

And with that the package built properly and scikit-learn imports properly:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>>
```

I'm not sure which of the three packages was the critical package, probably `libpython3.4-dev`, but the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You should clean up (remove) your local install and run `sudo apt-get install python-scikits-learn`.  It's packaged for debian so will also be packaged for Ubuntu and derivatives.

Install instructions for python libs often tell you to install things manually.  This is a mistake if the library has already been packaged for your distro - the distro package will be much better integrated into the system than following some install instructions on a web site.

The first thing you should do when you want to install a python library is to use tools like `apt-cache search` or `aptitude search` to find out if it is already packaged.  If it is, install the package.  If it isn't, you're probably better off using `deb-dry` or the `debhelper` tools to help you build a local package than to follow instructions that probably only work in the lib developer's own idiosyncratic environment.

Comment: The packaged version is for Python 2, and does not work for Python 3. Otherwise, this would be the correct answer.

Comment: you can use `deb-dry` etc to build a local package of the python3 version.  give it a different name like `python3-sklearn`

Comment: Thank you cas. I've updated the question mentioning that I need specifically Python 3 support. I also added an answer with the solution to the issue.

Comment: @dotancohen Building a Python 3 package (assuming it doesn't exist) if you have the python 2 package is probably easy. If you run into problems, you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, you should continue installation - and this would mean running build again, but with `sudo` this time. The reason why you couldn't install without sudo, is how the installation process for software looks like(most of the time).

1. Configuration step - you prepare files for building the program. This shouldn't need root priviliges.
2. Build step - you compile your program, yielding some executables and/or libraries. This shouldn't require root priviliges.
3. Installation - you move libraries and/or executables to their destination in OS, so that other programs can use it.

Build creates `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn` so that other programs can use it(e.g. python interpreter), and that's why you're getting an error.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I was able to build without sudo after configuring which ATLAS packages to use - see my answer for details.